# Fit div width to inline-block children

Tags: html, css

I want the container div (#a-container in this example) to fit the width of its children, that are inline-block divs. In this example, I want the `#a-container` div to be just the size of 2 .a div. Is it possible? (pure CSS please)

```css
#a-container {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: gray;
}
.a {
  background-color:blue;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="a-container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/r2fzxhf3/1/)?

Comment: Why do you want the container to be **smaller** than the total width of it's children?

Comment: This question is incorrectly marked as a duplicate. The answers on the supposed duplicated question do not work. [Here's jsfiddle showing the above example with the answer applied from the incorrectly linked duplicate](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/qbx3kfho/). In particular the question on the other page only has 1 child element. This question has multiple child elements and needs a different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that uses `display: table` and floating: http://jsfiddle.net/vqjnoqur/.

HTML:

```css
#a-container {
  display: table;
  background-color: gray;
}

.a {
  background-color:blue;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.a:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="a-container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to extend this solution so that it works for any number of divs per row?

Comment: Yeap, just change the formula in the last selector from `2n + 1` to something else: http://jsfiddle.net/25hLhLby/.  That's the beauty of `display: table` it shrinkwraps its content while still remaining essentially a block that also does not require clearing of floats.

Comment: Hi @DRD i want to know more about this **.a:nth-of-type(2n + 1)** can you explain .?? i wan to know the use of it.!!!